# How to break the string after X letters? PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would to know how to break the text to next line after the x letters in PHP.

Comment: So then you have to learn it.

Comment: Take a look at `wordwrap()`

Comment: Thank you very much @Rizier123!: )

Comment: @TomaszChwicewski You may want to put some more [effort into your question, may it be: research, attempts(even if they failed), pseudo code, ...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3933332). Also see [ask]

Comment: Not sure but these to may help you http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
wordwrap($text, $x_num_of_letters, $string_to_break, true);
```

`$x_num_of_letters` should be an integer, of course.

If you need to go to the next line in rendered HTML for example inside a `<p>`, you need to use `<br>` as `$string_to_break`. If you mean the next line of the file, use `\n` or `\n\r`.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `wordwrap()` function. This takes a string to wrap, a line length, what character to use to place between lines, and boolean specifying whether a line break should be forced if a word is very long.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
$str = "This is a very long string oh yes it is.";

$lineLength = 10;
$forceBreaks = true;
$wrapped = wordwrap($str, $lineLength, "\n", $forceBreaks);

echo $wrapped;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wordwrap` function that allows you to put a break line after X characters of a string: `wordwrap($yourString, $yourNumberOfCharacters, $breakLineToInsert);`

Example:

```
$yourString = "Hi, I'm a string and I wanna be broke by a breakpoint";
$yourNumberOfCharacters = 10; 
$newtext = wordwrap($yourString, $yourNumberOfCharacters, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
```

It will print:

```
Hi, I'm a <br />
string and<br />
I wanna b<br />
e broke by <br />
a breakpoi<br />
nt
```